# nested list struct c++

Tags: c++, struct, nested-lists

I have a nested list:

```
struct CHANNEL {
char channel_id[200];
char name_Channel[200];
};

struct Line {
CHANNEL* chan;
PROGRAM* prog;
HOST* host;
DATE_TIME* date;
struct Line* next;
};
```

but when I create a Line variable and try to work with it

```
    char number[200];
    Line* p;
    p = (struct Line*)malloc(sizeof(*p));

    strcpy_s(p->chan->channel_id, number);
```

Visual studio says: "Dereferencing NULL pointer 'p'" and "Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF." in string.h

How can it be fixed?

Comment: `sizeof(Line)` might work better than `sizeof(*p)` when `p` hasn't even been initialized ... Why are you even using malloc in C++?

Comment: This looks more C than C++. Don't try to learn C++ by learning C. (It also looks like far too many pointers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
p = (struct Line*)malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

Allocates memory for an object of `struct Line`.

It does **not** initialize the object.
One of the uninitialized data members of this object is `CHANNEL* chan`.
Therefore when you try to access `p->chan->channel_id`, `p->chan` is uninitialized and you cannot use it to access the `CHANNEL` struct members.

You can solve this specific issue by "manually" initializing the members of `p` after the allocation.

But if you are using c++ (as suggested by the tags you put on your question), it's better to use `new` which calls the object's constructor after performing the memory allocation. For this to work, you will need to add a constructor to `struct Line` that will initialize all the members (and specifically initialize the pointers like `CHANNEL* chan` to point to some valid `CHANNEL` object). Also in c++ it's usually prefered to use smart pointers over raw ones.